# get FileChannel without using java.io.* (use pure NIO)

Tags: java, file-io, copy, nio, channel

Recently I got a comment to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981533/java-file-not-written-to-stream-with-new-line-characters/1982069#1982069) that I should stay away from `java.io` if I want to use "pure NIO".
This is the simplified code (copy a file):

```
private static void copy(File source, File destination) throws IOException {
    long length = source.length();
    FileChannel input = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
    FileChannel output = new FileOutputStream(destination).getChannel();

    input.transferTo(0, length, output);

    output.close();
    input.close();
}
```

<sup>*(code extremely simplified: removed try-finally and loop)*</sup>

My question is how to get a `FileChannel` or other NIO class for reading a file without using java.io (`FileInputStream`)?

**EDIT:**
Java 6 (or before only)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [javadoc of FileChannel](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) says:

> This class does not define methods for opening existing files or for creating new ones; such methods may be added in a future release. In this release a file channel can be obtained from an existing FileInputStream, FileOutputStream, or RandomAccessFile object by invoking that object's getChannel method, which returns a file channel that is connected to the same underlying file.

That is, with java 1.6 you can't get a `FileChannel` without using old `java.io`.

Answer (score 7):

Java 6 only has `FileInputStream.getChannel()`, `FileOutputStream.getChannel()`, and `RandomAccessFile.getChannel()`

Java 7 has `java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(...)` and `java.nio.Files.newByteChannel(...)`