# How to create a copy of a file in the same directory in java?

Tags: java, file

I want all the features of file.renameTo in java but without the source file getting deleted.
For eg:
Say I have a file report.doc and I want to create the file report.xml without report.doc getting deleted. Also, the contents of both the files should be the same. (A simple copy)
How do I go about doing this?

I know this might be trivial but some basic searching didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For filesystem operations [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) provides useful shortcuts.

See:

- [FileUtils.html](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)
- [FileUtils.html#copyFile](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile(java.io.File,%20java.io.File))

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new File with the same content of the original.
Use the java NIO (Java 1.4 or later) for that:

```
private static void copy(File source, File destination) throws IOException {
    long length = source.length();
    FileChannel input = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
    try {
        FileChannel output = new FileOutputStream(destination).getChannel();
        try {
            for (long position = 0; position < length; ) {
                position += input.transferTo(position, length-position, output);
            }
        } finally {
            output.close();
        }
    } finally {
        input.close();
    }
}
```

see the answers for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981533/java-file-not-written-to-stream-with-new-line-characters/) for more